# HTML2PDF in Drupal module

Tags: php, pdf, drupal, html2pdf

I want to generate a PDF with the class Html2pdf in my drupal Module :

Here is my code :

```
$tab="<table>
<tr>
    <td>Salut!</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
";
try {
    $pdf=new HTML2PDF("P","A4","fr");
    $pdf->pdf->setDisplayMode("fullpage");
    $pdf->writeHTML($tab);
    $pdf->output("test.pdf");

} catch (HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
```

I have this error :
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file !!

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    $pdf=new HTML2PDF("P","A4","fr");
    $pdf->pdf->setDisplayMode("fullpage");
    $pdf->writeHTML($tab);
    $pdf->output("test.pdf");

    // Try to add this: 
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    // If you want you can add this too:
    print $pdf;
    drupal_exit();


} catch (HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
```

**ob_clean();**

Discards the contents of the output buffer.

**flush();**

Flushes the system write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push current output all the way to the browser with a few caveats.

Make sure you are also using the correct header information:

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

Comment: where you have to add the function :
drupal_add_http_header ??

I tested the code but it does not work !